# Any code that can "print" secured PDFs as an XPS document, then print that XPS document back into a PDF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, printing, xps

At my job, one of my daily tasks is to label incoming client documents and move them to a directory where a script uploads all the files in that directory to our Database Software.

A significant number of these incoming docs are PDFs, and there are a bunch throughout the day that are "Secured"; these documents screw up the uploading script because it can't convert the file to a .TIFF which is what our Database software reads. To unsecure these PDFs, I've been printing them as a Microsoft XPS file, and then printing the XPS file back into a PDF.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for some code (preferably Python 3 so I can add it to my file-moving script, but it's not a big deal whatever language it is) that will allow me to automate this process.

*It has to be **printed as an XPS** or else the PDF encryption won't be removed.*

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Can we assume that the "database software" is a document management/archival system? If so, it might be worthwhile to reconsider the system, because TIFF is extremely outdated for long term storage. Instead, you might better look at PDF/A -based solutions.

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes it is a document management system/archive. It's Unity's OnBase client. I'm nowhere close to being high enough on the totem pole to change our software, so I'm just trying to do the best I can with it.

Comment: About as bad as printing to XPS would be printing to PS, and then run through Distiller. Of course, all the useful metadata will be lost with that procedure.